# PDF.JS Error: No PDFJS.workerSrc specified even with compatibility.js

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I want to parse a PDF form to store the field contents to a sharepoint list using client side pdf.js lib.
In the web page, I referenced jquery, compatibility.js, pdf.js and pdf.worker.js (in that order), and created an upload field:

```
<input id="getFile" type="file"/>
<button onclick="pdfTest();return false;">uplod</button>
```

Button click calls this function:

```
function pdfTest() {
   var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
   var getFile = getFileBuffer();
   getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {
       PDFJS.getDocument(arrayBuffer).then(function (pdf) {
          // do stuff 
       })
   )};
}
```

The result is this:
Error: No PDFJS.workerSrc specified

at PDFJS.getDocument().
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try to specify path to pdf.worker.js? (no need to reference it in scripts)

Comment: Thanks, a PDFJS.workerSrc="<path to pdf.worker.js>"; seem to work!
pdf.js really lacks some comprehensive documentation.